# Vertical center an anchor tag within a fieldset

Tags: html, css, anchor, fieldset

I am trying to vertically center an anchor within a fieldset using CSS but it always appears to align to bottom. Is there any tricks to this?

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving too much detail here. Besides the line-height you might also want to tweak top and bottom padding. It all depends on how much stuff you have inside the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried specifying a **line-height** for the text? It should help to align in both Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the style **vertical-align:middle;**

```
<a href="www.google.com" style="vertical-align:middle;">google</a>
```

If that doesn't work posting your HTML would be helpful

Comment: This will only work on a table cell. Modern browsers will accept display: table-cell; which in conjunction with vert-align will work. Older browsers won't however.